# c# Word interop move cursor after the Shape

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, paragraph

I need to add a new paragraph after the shape object. In my code below I could not find the shape in saved Word document but getting the paragraph only.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wordApplication;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document wordDocument;
object missing = System.Type.Missing;
wordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(string.Empty, ref missing, ref missing,  ref  missing);
object outputFile = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\pttinu01", "Test1423.docx");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape oShape = null;
oShape = wordDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, CentimetersToPoints(5.6),  CentimetersToPoints(1.5), CentimetersToPoints(18), CentimetersToPoints(1.45), ref missing);
oShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Comic Sans MS";
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 18;
//oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray50;
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Shape";

object Count = 5;
wordApplication.ActiveDocument.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine,WdGoToDirection.wdGoToNext, ref Count,ref missing);

var pText = wordDocument.Paragraphs.Add();
// pText.Format.SpaceAfter = 10f;
pText.Range.Text = String.Format("This is line #{0}", "test para");
wordDocument.SaveAs(ref outputFile , ref missing, ref missing ...);                         
wordDocument = null;
wordApplication.Quit(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wordApplication = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert an image and then would like to continue writing the document tou probably would like to set the cursor to the end of the page.

This can be done like this :

```
//Set the cursor to the end of document.
Object toWhat = WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine;
Object toWhich = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast;
wordApp.Selection.GoTo(toWhat, toWhich, ref missing, ref missing);
```